# Field 'person_id' expected a number but got ''

Tags: python, django

i want to ask about my error , exactly the problem is that i pass a parameter `myid` to my method `newpost` , it is working good and i can print it before `if request.POST.get('postsubmit')` but after this if, when i print it or try to use it, it appears as blank `''`
i really did not understand the problem
please help

```
def newpost (request , myid ):
    
    print(myid)
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    if request.method == 'POST' & request.POST.get('postsubmit') :
         print(myid) 
         if request.POST.get('postsubmit'):
              print( myid)
              if myid not in blockedperson :
                print ("not blocked")
                savepost=post()
                savepost.person_id= myid
                savepost.content=request.POST.get('postcontent')
                savepost.p_date=dt.datetime.now()
                savepost.save() 
              else :
                blocked="sorry you are blocked , you can not share posts, contact with IT to more information at 437819147@kku.edu.sa"
                return render (request,'home.html',{'block':blocked})
    allpost=post.objects.all()
    allperson=person.objects.all()
    allstudent=student.objects.all()
    allteacher=teacher.objects.all()
    allcomp=company_rep.objects.all()

    return render (request,'home.html',{'posts':allpost , 'person':allperson,'student':allstudent,'teacher':allteacher,'comp':allcomp})
```

error is here (my id is 437819147) to be clear

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
app.company_rep.comp_id: (fields.W122) 'max_length' is ignored when used with IntegerField.
        HINT: Remove 'max_length' from field
app.person.person_id: (fields.W122) 'max_length' is ignored when used with IntegerField.
        HINT: Remove 'max_length' from field
app.post.person_id: (fields.W122) 'max_length' is ignored when used with IntegerField.
        HINT: Remove 'max_length' from field
app.post.post_code: (fields.W122) 'max_length' is ignored when used with AutoField.
        HINT: Remove 'max_length' from field
app.student.stu_id: (fields.W122) 'max_length' is ignored when used with IntegerField.
        HINT: Remove 'max_length' from field
app.student.year_of_graduat: (fields.W122) 'max_length' is ignored when used with IntegerField.
        HINT: Remove 'max_length' from field
app.teacher.teach_id: (fields.W122) 'max_length' is ignored when used with IntegerField.
        HINT: Remove 'max_length' from field

System check identified 7 issues (0 silenced).

You have 21 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, redirects, sessions, sites.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
April 05, 2021 - 17:13:00
Django version 3.1.7, using settings 'kkuproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:57872/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Apr/2021 17:13:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7718
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[05/Apr/2021 17:13:01] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2775
437819147
[05/Apr/2021 17:13:08] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 13734
[05/Apr/2021 17:13:09] "GET /static/css/Stylesheet1.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3419
[05/Apr/2021 17:13:09] "GET /static/css/img/signout.png HTTP/1.1" 200 14211
[05/Apr/2021 17:13:09] "GET /static/css/img/kku.png HTTP/1.1" 200 86406
[05/Apr/2021 17:13:09] "GET /static/css/img/message.png HTTP/1.1" 200 25921
[05/Apr/2021 17:13:09] "GET /static/css/img/search.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7673
[05/Apr/2021 17:13:09] "GET /static/css/img/back.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 174108



not blocked
Internal Server Error: /0/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\kkuproject\kkuproject\app\views.py", line 176, in newpost
    savepost.save()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 754, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 792, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 935, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1396, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1341, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1341, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1340, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1281, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 823, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 818, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1778, in get_prep_value
    ) from e
ValueError: Field 'person_id' expected a number but got ''.
[05/Apr/2021 17:13:13] "POST /0/ HTTP/1.1" 500 139491
```

Comment: The variable whose value is `''` is `myid` **not** `request.POST.get('postsubmit')`. (You have written `print(myid)` in all the places you expect something, also you write `savepost.person_id= myid` which causes an error since that is just an empty string)

Comment: i know that `myid` when we enter to `if request.POST.get('postsubmit')` it be blank , but before that `if` it is not blank , it is `437819147`